# Unix: Identify charset of vi editor

Tags: unix, hadoop2

I have a file which when I open in VI editor appears like below:

```
12´<9d>00
12b600
12É¹00
12çâ00
12Wj00
12«À00
12ùa00
12={00
12°l00
12P¹00
12Ë+00
12^T^^
12±B00
12zN00
12<8e>·00
12^T=00
12E<8f>00
12nß00
```

The same data in CAT or Windows appears as below:

```
12��00
12b600
12ɹ00
12��00
12Wj00
12��00
12�a00
12={00
12�l00
12P�00
12�+00
1200 --> 4 char
12�B00
12zN00
12��00
12=00 --> 5 char
12E�00
12n�00
```

I have been struggling with this data in reading as UTF-8 in windows/HDFS, as it reads as 6 char or 5 char or 4 char. If I can identify the way vi editor displays, I can read the file each line with 6 chars. When I do OD-C it displays as 2 char + 2 bytes + 2 char. Any help in this please.

Comment: on od -c I get something like this: 1 2 264 235 0 0 \n 1 2 b 6 0 0 \n 1 2 311 271 0 0 \n 1 2 347 342 0 0 \n 1 2 W j 0 0 \n 1 2 253 300 0 0 \n 1 2 371 a 0 0

Answer (score 0):

"vi" (whether it's actually **vi** or **vim**), cannot tell.  In the second part of the question, the odd-looking question marks are the Unicode *replacement character*, hinting that you're sending a non-UTF-8 file to a terminal which uses UTF-8.

That could be any of several 8-bit character sets/encodings (such as the ISO-8859-*x* series, or perhaps none of those).  Since the file does not appear to be *text*, but rather some type of data, the actual character set may not matter much.

This line contains a **`8F`** which is non-printable in the ISO character sets, but can be printable in the IBM/Microsoft DOS code pages (which are widely used or imitated in Easter Europe and Russia):

```
12E<8f>00
```

Ultimately, the way you can determine the character set is by knowing what the data is supposed to represent, and trying different translations (using `iconv` or `recode`) until you see a usable result in UTF-8.